# where does apache james store (failed) outgoing messages

Tags: apache-2.2, email, database, email-server

From the [james](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html) console:

```
jvm 1    | INFO  11:01:03,519 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting delivery of Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost to host bounceme.net. at 166.90.15.238 from fubar@wtf for addresses [thufir@localhost]
jvm 1    | INFO  11:02:03,579 | james.mailetcontext | Could not connect to SMTP host: 166.90.15.238, port: 25
jvm 1    | INFO  11:02:03,580 | james.mailetcontext | Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost: 
jvm 1    | INFO  11:02:03,580 | james.mailetcontext | Storing message Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost into outgoing after 0 retries
```

I don't expect the message to get get delivered.  However, where is the message stored?

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ cat conf/james-database.properties 
# MySQL JDBC database properties
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/james
database.username=james
database.password=password
vendorAdapter.database=MYSQL
openjpa.streaming=false

thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ mysql -u james -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 121
Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use james;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

I don't see anything in `/var/mail`:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ ll /var/mail
total 12
drwxrwsr-x  2 root   mail 4096 Aug 16 12:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root 4096 Aug 21 03:40 ../
-rw-------  1 news   mail 3680 Aug 14 09:23 news
-rw-------  1 root   mail    0 Aug 16 12:50 root
-rw-------  1 thufir mail    0 Aug 16 01:59 thufir
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ ll /var/mail/thufir
-rw------- 1 thufir mail 0 Aug 16 01:59 /var/mail/thufir
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ nl /var/mail/thufir
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ cat /var/mail/thufir
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

But I'm not sure what to look for.  It seems to point back to the james folder and the james logs, which, so far, don't shed much light on this.

This information is duplicated in the logs:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ tail log/james-server.log
INFO  11:20:39,415 | james.mailetcontext | Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost: 
INFO  11:20:39,416 | james.mailetcontext | Storing message Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost into outgoing after 2 retries
INFO  12:05:42,471 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting delivery of Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost to host bounceme.net. at 166.90.15.238 from fubar@wtf for addresses [thufir@localhost]
INFO  12:06:42,530 | james.mailetcontext | Could not connect to SMTP host: 166.90.15.238, port: 25
INFO  12:06:42,530 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting delivery of Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost to host bounceme.net. at 166.90.15.238 from fubar@wtf for addresses [thufir@localhost]
INFO  12:07:42,570 | james.mailetcontext | Could not connect to SMTP host: 166.90.15.238, port: 25
INFO  12:07:42,571 | james.mailetcontext | Attempting delivery of Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost to host bounceme.net. at 166.90.15.238 from fubar@wtf for addresses [thufir@localhost]
INFO  12:07:49,632 | james.mailetcontext | Could not connect to SMTP host: 166.90.15.238, port: 25
INFO  12:07:49,632 | james.mailetcontext | Temporary exception delivering mail (Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost: 
INFO  12:07:49,632 | james.mailetcontext | Storing message Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost into outgoing after 3 retries
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

However, no information appears in the logs, which I see, indicating exactly where message `Mail1345571942295-bf02a4ca-791c-4776-a194-809aba6e4c1a-to-localhost` is stored in "outgoing".  What does that log message mean?

Comment: Have you checked in /var/mail folder?

Comment: @Chida  I added that to the question, but it doesn't add information which I understand.

Comment: shouldn't there be tables in the james mysql database for james to store data?

Comment: Exactly.  I can't find documentation on whether James creates that, or I create that.  the [schema](http://james.apache.org/server/3/dev-database-schema.html) is one thing, but, the log clearly shows that James is saving mail to **somewhere**, but where is that?

Comment: True. See step 9 from this link -- http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html this might help debug some more

Comment: @Chida I added log file output, I've looked through the logs without seeing anything which explains this to me.  Nor do I see anything in var, except some derby files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4584/discussion-between-thufir-and-chida)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually `$JAMES_DIR/var/mail/error`.